# How do you get DimIteration table information from Azure Devops Services into Power BI?

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi

Our company is transitioning from TFS on-premises to Azure Devops Service so all of our internal team reporting that uses the TFS_Warehouse will no longer work.  I am able to pull work item information from analytics views, but do not know how to pull data such as Iteration data (formerly in DimIteration in TFS_Warehouse) into Power BI.  Can anyone assist?  I'm starting from scratch here with very little knowledge about Azure Devops or using Power BI outside of R scripting or Import queries from SQL Server, so as much information as anyone could provide on how to do this through Power BI & Azure Devops would be most appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you have a try with below solution. Any good news?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-iteration-paths-sprints?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) to check about project and team iterations/areas information in azure devops.

You can get the iterations information by calling [Restful Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/iterations/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

```
 curl -u {username}[:{personalaccesstoken}]https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?api-version=5.1
```

You can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get started with Azure DevOps Services REST API.

Check the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops) to get your PAT(personal access token)

To import the iteration data into powerBI, You can try below steps.

Choose Get Data From Web, and enter the url and authentication header.
[image]

Hope you will find above helpful!