# Access Azure DevOps analytic data via Power BI using a different PAT

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, odata

I'm trying to create reporting against work items in Azure DevOps from PowerBI for my entire organization.  But I don't have access to all of the projects, so the odata connector returns an error.  (per the last statement on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/analytics-security?view=azure-devops)

Can I use a different PAT through Power BI?  I don't see a way to do this.

I tried following the answer from [How do you get DimIteration table information from Azure Devops Services into Power BI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58527971/how-do-you-get-dimiteration-table-information-from-azure-devops-services-into-po) with a PAT I was given and a variety of URLS, but did not work.

And I'm using Power BI (not writing C#, Java, etc.), so I don't see where the [Authentication Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops) fits into my solution.

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue?If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I use a different PAT through Power BI?

Do you mean changing authentication credentials? If so you can go through the following steps:

Click File > Options and Settings > Data Source Settings. Select the correct URL to the OData Feed and click Edit.

[image]

Click the `Edit Permissions` button under the Credentials setting.

[image]

Edit the credentials as noted above, click Save, then Done, then Close.

For details ,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/report/powerbi/client-authentication-options?view=azure-devops#change-authentication-credentials). If I misunderstood the issue, please indicate.

Comment: Technically, this answers the question I asked.